# Odoo (OpenERP) custom field error

Tags: customization, odoo

I've added a custom field to the Invoice model called x_contract_currency_rate which is a float field. I've added the field into the view and it's working OK on existing invoices.

If I try to add a new invoice it throws me the error below and the invoice form will not load. As far as I can tell it's got something to do with the field's default value, but I have not set a default nor do I see an option to do so.

Odoo Server Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py",
>   line 518, in _handle_exception return super(JsonRequest,
>   self)._handle_exception(exception) File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py",
>   line 539, in dispatch result = self._call_function(**self.params) File
>   "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 295, in _call_function return
>   checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs) File
>   "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper return
>   f(dbname, *args, **kwargs) File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 292,
>   in checked_call return self.endpoint(*a, **kw) File
>   "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 755, in **call** return
>   self.method(*args, **kw) File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 388,
>   in response_wrap response = f(*args, **kw) File
>   "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 949, in call_kw
>   return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs) File
>   "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 941, in _call_kw
>   return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr,
>   request.uid, *args, **kwargs) File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line
>   237, in wrapper return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs) File
>   "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 332, in old_api result = method(recs,
>   *args, **kwargs) File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 1337, in default_get defaults[name] = field.default(self) File
>   "/opt/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 379, in  func(recs), recs,
>   validate=False, File "/opt/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 375, in
>    func = lambda recs: value(recs._model, recs._cr, recs._uid,
>   recs._context) File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
>   return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs) File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py",
>   line 332, in old_api result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs) File
>   "/opt/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 363, in  lambda recs:
>   self.convert_to_write(value(recs)) File "/opt/odoo/openerp/fields.py",
>   line 1490, in convert_to_write return value.id AttributeError: 'int'
>   object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: I guess this error comes from your custom modules. This error says "try to access `id` with `integer object`" If you change that int object to `browse record` than no longer face this error. You can access any value with `browse record` but can not with int object.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably doing something like:

```
default=<id>
```

where you should actually be doing:

```
default=<record>
```

when declaring a new field.